# Call to a member function query() on resource

Tags: php, mysql

okay guys so i was just writing the code for an admin panel just for fun, and i ran into a problem when i copied some code from w3schools.
Can someone tell me where i am wrong.

**Here's My Code**

```
    <?php
  $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","","ATFlogin");
$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: What did you try to correct it ? What is your error ? mysql is deprecated, at least write with PDO or mysqli...

Comment: _Can someone tell me where i am wrong_ **You copied some code from w3schools**

Comment: my error is [call to a member function query() on resource]

Comment: Edit your question and add the full text of the error message you are getting.

Comment: You need to add error checking. Apparently, your connection failed.

Comment: Also, mysql functions are depreciated, and have been removed from the current version of PHP. Use either PDO or mysqli functions

Comment: `mysql_` functions do not have a OO ability either

Answer (score 0):

it Looks like you are trying to mix mysql with mysqli.

Change your connection to be:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","ATFlogin");
```

Read up on MySQLI [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

mysql functions have all been depracted and mysqli is the successor so if possible use mysqli.